# XML to XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to edit a single XML element; I am attempting to rename this element to something else, but I dont think I am doing it right. see below. XML I wish to alter. for now I just want to alter `<test1>` to `<blah>`.

```
<Csv>    
<Row rowNo="1">    
<test1>1999-01-02T10:30:20</test1>   
<test2>200</test2>   
<test3>17</test3>    
<test4>1</test4>    
<test5>15</test5>   
<test6>10</test6>    
<test7>210</test7>    
<test8>main strip Top</test8>    
<test9>Tyre Check</test9>   
</Row>   
<Row rowNo="2">
<test1>2014-03-08T10:30:20</test1>    
<test2>200</test2>    
<test3>17</test3>    
<test4>1</test4>    
<test5>45</test5>    
<test6>14</test6>    
<test7>520</test7>   
<test8>main strip Left</test8>    
<test9>Tyre Fixed</test9>
```

Below is my XSL transfer method on doing so.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xe.source ../output.xml#Csv?><xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" media-type="text/xml"></xsl:output>
  <xsl:template match="/"></xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Row/test1">      
    <xsl:element name="blah">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>          
  </xsl:template>           
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am unable to replace the element with the new name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this template match

```
<xsl:template match="/"></xsl:template>
```

`/` matches the document node, which is the parent of the root `Csv` element. You are matching it, and then effectively stopping processing, so no other templates in your XSLT will be be matched.

If you remove that template match, it will work as expected.